# Odoo 9 Keyboard controls over input fields (one2many)

Tags: javascript, cursor, focus, odoo-9, tabindex

Is there any way to control key (cursor) flow, like when you press tab on keyboard, the cursor shifts from one input field to another. But when suppose in sales order under product line the cursor is not coming instead it skips this whole section. Is there any way or solution for this?

[image]

Comment: just added a new attribute on tree view editable="bottom" and editable="top"  in that way u may solve your issue

Comment: Yes, already using editable="bottom" but while editing record cursor shows in "Add an item" instead of first row first field focus.

Comment: Have u tried options attribute on field level  ?

Comment: I tried default_focus in the field inside tree editable="bottom". 
But Edit record not focusing in first row fields it focus on "Add an item".